# Make stab for method throwing an exception in Mockito partial mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to Mockito and I need to use a partial mock of a class `ClassToTest1` and call real method `somethingToTestVoid`. But the problem is this method calls another method `doSomething`, that throws an exception and I need just to make a stub for it.

```
public class ClassToTest1 {

    private ClassToTest2 c2;

    public ClassToTest2 getC2() {
        return c2;
    }

    public void setC2(ClassToTest2 c2) {
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    public void somethingToTestVoid() throws Exception {
        c2 = new ClassToTest2();
        c2.doSomething();
        System.out.println("OK!");
    }
}


public class ClassToTest2 {

    public ClassToTest2() {
    }

    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("");
    }
}
```

And in a test class I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
          ClassToTest1 c1 = Mockito.mock(ClassToTest1.class);
          Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(c1).somethingToTestVoid();
          Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(c1).setC2(Mockito.any());
          ClassToTest2 c2 = Mockito.mock(ClassToTest2.class);
          c1.setC2(c2);

          Mockito.doNothing().when(c2).doSomething();
          c1.somethingToTestVoid();
    }
```

But still Exception is thrown in `doSomething`, because mocked `c2` and c2 which is used in `somethingToTestVoid` are different objects.

Comment: Shouldn't `Mockito.doNothing().when(c2.doSomething());` be `Mockito.doNothing().when(c2).doSomething();` ? I don't know if that's line 53

Comment: You may find some useful ideas [in my article here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer, maybe a little messy, but it works.

```
public class ClassToTest1 {

private ClassToTest2 c2;

public ClassToTest2 getC2() {
    if (c2 == null) {
        c2 = new ClassToTest2();
    };
    return c2;
}

public void setC2(ClassToTest2 c2) {
    this.c2 = c2;
}

public void somethingToTestVoid() throws Exception {
    getC2().doSomething();
    System.out.println("OK!");
    }
}

public class ClassToTest2 {

    public ClassToTest2() {
    }

    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("");
    }
}


@Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        ClassToTest1 c1 = new ClassToTest1();
        c1 = Mockito.spy(c1);
        ClassToTest2 c2 = Mockito.spy(new ClassToTest2());

        Mockito.doReturn(c2).when(c1).getC2();
        Mockito.doNothing().when(c2).doSomething();
        c1.somethingToTestVoid();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `somethingToTestVoid()` initializes new instance of `c2` via `new`

```
c2 = new ClassToTest2();
```

make it impossible to test your case with just Mockito without any changes.

One of the options is to refactor this line to factory method (or some kind of DI). It seems that you should have called `getC2()`

```
public void somethingToTestVoid() throws Exception {
    c2 = getC2();
    c2.doSomething();
    System.out.println("OK!");
}
```

in this case you test should pass.

The other option is to use [PowerMock](http://powermock.github.io/) to intercept `ClassToTest2` object creation and mock it. The framework also has means to mock static methods. All the things you should not have to do in good app.